# Is there an easy way to set up a home FTP server?

Tags: server, ftp

I have more then one computer at home, and I would really like if I could set up a home FTP server to access all of the files?

The WiFi router is connected to a PC that runs Ubuntu 12.10 and files are stored on it that I want to access from other systems. The other systems are — two PCs that use Windows 8 and with one that uses Windows 7. Will it work?

So is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing would be to use SFTP. It has the advantage of being encrypted (communicating over SSH). To install a server for SSH/SFTP, press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then use `ifconfig` to find out the IP address of your computer. You can then connect to it from other computers using this address.

If your computer is running ubuntu, just select the "Connect to server" option (I don't use unity, but it should be easy enough to find. You will get a window like the picture below. Make sure to use the correct IP address and enter your username and password.

[image: Connect to server]

If you need to connect from a Windows computer, you can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Comment: One question if you do not mind will it work on set up like this.
  so the wifi router is connected to a pc that runs ubuntu 12.10 and files are stored on it that i want to access from other systems other systems are two pc that use windows 8 and with one that uses 7 will it work ??

Comment: Yes, it should work just fine. I've never used Windows 8, but I don't see any reason why it would be a problem.

Comment: I am sorry do not want to bother you but I can not find an app that will allow me to set up ftp on 12.10

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "finding an app"? If you're trying to use software center, that won't work. Run the command above in a terminal.

Answer (score 6):

FTP or SFTP are poor choices in a home network if you need seamless access on multiple types of clients and operating systems. Samba is a better choice because it works with Windows, Linux and Mac very well.

The filesystem can be easily mounted to all those platforms enabling direct access to the files without copying it locally first.

Start here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on ftp, look at [FTP Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/ftp-server.html)

However, I agree with Peter Jenkins' answer that [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba) is the way to go in a multiple OS environment. You will be able to mount the Samba shares from Linux, Windows, Mac, ... and access the files.

Note, one side effect of using Samba is if you delete a file on a Samba share using a file browser (Nautilus, Windows Explorer, Mac Finder ...), it is gone, as in it does not go to the trash can.  Samba can "recycle" files, however this needs to be setup in smb.conf to [recycle](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/samba-recycle-bin-tip-723004).  Deleted files don't go to a trash can, but to a place designated in the smb.conf.